# Rails 3.1 Pipeline - Exclude Javascript File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I want to exclude a particular javascript file (modernizr) from the pipeline because I want it to load separately.

I want to load Modernizr at the beginning and the rest of my javascript concatenated at the end.

Is there way to do the opposite of a require in the asset pipeline in 3.1?  ie.  an exclude?

Thanks in advance.

Adam.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I chose to keep the sprockets functionality by changing

```
//= require_tree
```

to

```
//= require_directory .
```

This keeps sprockets auto-loading any files in the same directory, but not in any folders further.

This allowed me to move Modernizr.js to the assets/javascripts/top folder and manually load it at the top with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "top/modernizr" %>
```

and move

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

To the bottom of my application.html.erb file (above the closing body tag)

Comment: should be 'top/modernizr' for it to find your file ;)

Comment: Thanks Adam. In addition, when I deploy to production, I need to add this code `config.assets.precompile += ['top/*.js', 'top/*.css']` in production.rb, otherwise it will fail in my server.

Answer (score 23):

I realize this is an old question, but Google sent me here last week so it's not an obsolete question.  The answer I found elsewhere was [the "stub" directive for sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#stub).  So something like

```
//= require-tree .
//= stub Modernizr
```

This keeps Modernizr.js out of the bundled assets.  It can be included with its own tag, à la the original answer.

The Sprockets changelog says "stub" was added in January 2012, so it wouldn't have been available at the time this question was first answered, but I think it's a good answer now.

Comment: @mcdave Yep its really helpful.

Comment: This is the best solution when it's about single files.

Answer (score 15):

This is far easier accomplished by going to your config/environments/production.rb file and adding the following line

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( modernizr.js )
```

Then when you precompile your assets modernizer will have it's own separate file that you can use in your head.

Comment: Thanks.  This works.  What I chose to do was keep my root directly auto-loaded, and have any separate folders contain manually loaded files.  so in vendors > assets > javascripts > top I put modernizr.js.  While everything in assets > javascripts still gets loaded with sprockets.  using:    //= require_directory .   in my application.js

Comment: In rails 4, this can be added in the config/initializers/assets.rb file as like below: Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( modernizr.js )

Answer (score 2):

These answers are outdated. Just move `active_admin.css.scss` from `app/assets/stylesheets` to `vendor/assets/stylesheets`.

Do the same with `active_admin.js.coffee` (move from `app/assets/javascripts` to `vendor/assets/javascripts`).

Your assets will then be loaded when needed, and you won't have to make modifications to `applications.js` to accommodate active_admin.

This solution is described in [this issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/825). Hope this helps.