# How to tell Rails asset pipeline to ignore certain file types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, asset-pipeline

Is it possible to have the asset pipeline ignore certain file types?

I store a number of GeoIP files in `vendor/assets`. The asset pipeline automatically precompiles them and places them in the `public/` directory, even though they're only used by background tasks and never need to be served to the public.

Is there a way to exclude these files from precompilation or is my only option to move them elsewhere?

---

Running Rails 3.2.1 and deploying with Capistrano

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061575/rails-3-1-pipeline-exclude-javascript-file

Comment: @meagar that's the intention, they're only used within the Rails app itself for background tasks so keeping them out of the `public` directory is the whole idea. The only place they are referenced is within an initializer and that's it.