# dynamic asset loading heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm implementing a site tour feature for the website https://looky.co, and I want to only send the `site_tour.js` file when a `show_site_tour` is set to true. (`show_site_tour` is a database column).

I have it set up in my application.html.haml (layout file). The problem is with the way heroku runs the asset pipeline.

Directory structure

```
\ app
   \ assets
      \ javascripts
         \ guiders
            site_tour.js
```

Basically the problem is that when I try to include that folder only on the condition that the database column is equal to true, heroku gives an "asset not precompiled" error.

In my application.html.haml

```
%head
  = javascript_include_tag 'application'
  - if current_user.show_site_tour == true
    = javascript_include_tag 'guiders/site_tour'
```

So how can I make this work with the heroku pipeline?
Basically the main question is, how can I have more than one javascript file on heroku?

Comment: Can you post the output of `heroku logs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061575/rails-3-1-pipeline-exclude-javascript-file).

Basically, you need to tell the asset pipeline to keep the `site_tour` file separate.

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( guiders/site_tour )
```

You should end up with two JavaScript files after this setting takes affect, `application.js` and `site_tour.js`.

You can test this locally by precompiling the assets using `rake`.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

This will show you how the output will end up on Heroku.

It's probably also worth noting that [Heroku requires that you have the following setting set to false](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets).

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```