# How do I make a Javascript asset public for a CORS Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, cors

I am in the process of building a Rails application that uses CORS and has a public API.  For the API to work, clients will need to embed a Javascript file that I host on my website.  So for example, they will need to add the following to *their* website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/assets/events.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Call to public API method
  track();
</script>
```

Right now the **events.js** file is located in `/app/assets/javascripts/events.js` in my app.  And when I compile and push to Heroku, it's all being minified together into the `/assets/application-320d973ae0689d7f.js` file.

My question is, how do I make the **events.js** file a standalone file accessible to outside websites from my app with a direct URL path?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3.1 Pipeline - Exclude Javascript File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061575/rails-3-1-pipeline-exclude-javascript-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by creating an `assets` folder in the `public` directory and moving the `events.js` file into it.  I didn't have to change any of the production settings.

Answer (score 5):

**Public**

We've achieved this functionality before by placing the javascript into the `public` directory:

```
#public/events.js
...
```

This allows you to give people the following URL:

```
<script src="http://domain.com/events.js"></script>
```

Although this will **not** be tied into your asset pipeline, it will give you a central file which you'll be able to call whenever you require it. This is very important, as if you have third-parties referencing a file, you need them to at least have a single point of reference.

---

**CORS**

Giving a single reference is vital for the [CORS policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) of your application, as you have to give an explicit "resource" to offer. I would recommend the use of the [rack-cors gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) for this by the way:

```
#config/application.rb
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
   allow do
     origins '*'
     resource '/events.js', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get]
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestion!  I got to this to work by simply placing the file in the public folder, like you mentioned.  For my purposes, it was enough to get my app to work properly.  But I will definitely have to read-up on the rack-cors gem.  Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

1. precompile your assets,
2. turn on serve static assets
3. place the events.js file in the public folder

that should do it